# Python: Reading a global variable inside a function creator

Tags: python

So, I want to create a function creator that reads a global variable every time it's called, and not just when it's created. That's not the case, since Python replaces my var reference with it's current value.

```
import operator

space = []
pp = 0 #this is a global var

def op(op,*tval,over = 0, doSave = True):
     def operation():
        val = list(tval)
        val.append(space[pp]) # This apparently becomes val.append(space[0])
        temp = op(*val)
        if doSave:
                 space[pp] = temp # This apparently becomes space[0] = temp
     return operation

increase = op(operator.add, 1, doSave = True)
```

Increase only works with space[0] and even if I change pp, it only modifies the first value of space.

Comment: Where do you change pp? Also your return statement is not inside the function.

Comment: Indentation changed when I copied the code here. Just fixed it. (The idea is that I will want to change pp in the future. For example, a will do "pp = 5; increase() ")

Answer (score 0):

```
return operation
```

should be indented.

You should have

```
global space
```

to change `space`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I correctly understood what you are trying to achieve, you need to make `pp` a global. Just add `global pp` right after `def op(..)`.

You are using a closure to create the operator, therefore Python will bind the current value of `pp` (i.e. 0) instead that an alias to the global variable. If you declare pp as a global variable then the alias will be bound instead (Python will understand that you may change that).

Another (minor) improvement would be to change the name of your function from `op` to something like `make_operator(op, *args, doSave=True)`. It does not change the functionality but it improves readability.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks for the advice.